# GCP project billing reports

Tags: gcp

I want to download GCP project billing reports linked to billing account and send them to another platform. This process should occur daily at a specific time.
Explored Python client libraries but couldn't find relevant API documentation for downloading GCP project billing reports linked to billing accounts.

Comment: Have you already contacted the vendor by opening a support ticket? Kindly also refer to [ask] for additional information.